# SQLPlus variable definition

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I want to do this in SQLPlus: define a file which contains today's date in its name and spool off the output of a SQL statement to that file. I know how to spool the output of an SQL statement to a file. Just don't know how to declare the file name as a variable containing today's date.

For example, select all the rows with today's timestamp from ERROR table and output the results to a file called `TODAYS_ERRORS_YYYYMMDD.log`.

I am using a BAT file which invokes SQL plus as follows:

```
sqlplus -silent user/password@errorDB @c:\temp\error_query.sql
```

I am able to run the above bat file and output the rows successfully to a file with a static file name, such as `TODAYS_ERRORS.log`. Just don't know how to declare the file name so that it contains today's date in its name.

This is how my `error_query.sql` file looks right now:

```
set feedback off;
set echo off;

spool c:\temp\TODAYS_ERRORS.log

SELECT created_time      AS "Created Time",
       error_severity    AS "Severity",
       error_desc        AS "Error Text"
FROM ERROR
WHERE
  to_date(to_char(created_time,'YYYYMMDD') = to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD');

spool off;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

SPOOL with dynamic file name.
http://www.lazydba.com/oracle/0__57310.html

Also, DOS command can be written to get the date.
1st link when searching: DOS + Batch + Date -> http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic name for your spool file as follows:

```
col datum new_value today
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') as datum from dual;

set heading off
set linesize 128
set echo off
set feedback off

spool today_&today..log
rem Your query here ...     
select ...
/
spool off
```